# Особенности работы с сокетами

Tags: c++, tcp-ip

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите пожалуйста, если у меня есть сокет и в нем есть инфа, которую я ещё не вычитал. Если я в этот сокет запишу другую инфу на отправку, смогу ли я вычитать инфу, которая пришла до этой записи, позже?

Comment: Да, сможете. Буфера приема и отправки независимы